# Exclude CMS Block and CMS Pages from Data Migration Tool Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

is it possible to exclude CMS blocks and CMS pages from migrateion magento1 to magento2 using Magento Migration Tool? We only need products, categories, rewiews, orders, customer ...

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: yes you can migrate using migration tool

Comment: I need to exlude them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.2/map.xml.dist
```

**Rename This File To `map.xml`**

> **In Your config.xml file Chnage this :-**
>
> **From :-**
>
> `<map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.2/map.xml.dist</map_file>`
>
> **To :-**
>
> `<map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.2/map.xml</map_file>`

**In Your map.xml File Just Add Table Which You Want to Ignore under the `source` `document_rules` Tag**

```
<source>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>cms_block</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_block_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>core_config_data</document>
        </ignore>           
    </document_rules>
</source>
```

**No Other Changes In Map.xml File Just Add Your Table**

Comment: Thanks - but I have already installed and migrated data successfull. I just need to know how to except "cms blocks and pages" from migration. I do not need cms blocks and pages on new magento 2 installation

Comment: i am not sure with but after migration you can truncate that table

Comment: cms_block,cms_block_store,cms_page,cms_page_store 4 table for blocks and pages

Comment: thanks. but this is we can not do. we have new theme installed and migration tool is overwriting pages and blocks. we do need them at all to migrate

Comment: please check answer

Comment: thanks! I will try it!

Comment: hm .. it is not working. I changed in config.xml then line:
 <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map.xml</map_file>
and added following to map.xml:
<map....../../map.xsd">
    <source>
        <document_rules>
   <ignore>
     <document>cms_block</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
     <document>cms_block_store</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
     <document>cms_page</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
     <document>cms_page_store</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
     <document>core_config_data</document>
</ignore>   
        ...
but it is not working ... can you please help!

Comment: try this........

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: wel come bro.....

Comment: Just a note. The url rewrites do get migrated for CMS pages so that has to be taken care of by maybe re-generating url rewrites with some extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all cms from

   data-migration-tool/etc/edition-to-edition/version/map.xml
2. Ignore them in:

   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/edition-to-edition/settings.xml

So you need copy or rename settings.xml.dist to settings.xml

Good article you can find here:

https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-migration